# Error handler working even without errors

Tags: vba, excel

I've quite new to Excel VBA and I have trouble regarding error handler (using On Error Goto [label]). My code somewhat follows this flow:

```
StartDate = Format(Cells(11, 4).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
EndDate = Format(Cells(12, 4).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

For Each WS In Worksheets
    If WS.Name Like "WS_Name" Then
        Exist = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next

On Error GoTo EHandler: '[ERROR HANDLER POINT A]
If Exist = True Then
    On Error GoTo EHandler: '[ERROR HANDLER POINT B]
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WS_Name").Select
    Sheets("WS_Name").Cells.ClearContents
    With 'some code that uses the StartDate and EndDate in a SQL query in a database
    End With
Else
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "WS_Name"
    With 'some code that uses the StartDate and EndDate in a SQL query in a database
    End With
End If
Exit Sub

EHandler:
    'some code that would show the error number and desc

End Sub
```

I would like to set an error handler for the event that the user might enter an earlier EndDate than my StartDate. I tried inserting the On Error Goto [label] on ERROR HANDLER POINTS A & B and have varying results.

If my On Error Goto [label] is on POINT A, EHandler doesn't work.

If my On Error Goto [label] is on POINT B, EHandler works even if the dates enter are correct.

How do I go about this one?

Comment: Shouldn't `EndDate = 'some code` know the `StartDate` so the check is done early?

Comment: `If Exist = True Then` becomes `If Exist Then` and  `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WS_Name").Select :  Sheets("WS_Name").Cells.ClearContents` becomes `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("WS_Name").Cells.ClearContents` (at least!).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code can be reduced to this (notice your With statements still don't have an object referenced).

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    StartDate = Format(Cells(11, 4).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")
    EndDate = Format(Cells(12, 4).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd")

    If EndDate < StartDate Then
        MsgBox "End Date is earlier than StartDate. Please select an end date after the start date."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each WS In Worksheets

        If WS.Name Like "WS_Name" Then
            Exist = True
            Exit For
        End If

    Next

    If Exist Then

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WS_Name").Cells.ClearContents

        With                                   'some code that uses the StartDate and EndDate in a SQL query in a database

        End With

    Else

        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add.Name = "WS_Name"

        With                                    'some code that uses the StartDate and EndDate in a SQL query in a database

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect (but don't know for certain) that the code between the `With/End` is the same so some more repetition could be excluded. The `With` is probably `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("WS_Name")`.

Comment: Yup..... I think you are probably right and it was really annoying me to leave it as it... the red warnings were driving me nut nuts....... And I'm sorry your comment above didn't show until after I posted this. Seems some slow page refreshing.

Comment: more like my slow typing :-)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to set an error handler for the event that the user might
>   enter an earlier EndDate than my StartDate.

```
If EndDate < StartDate Then
    ' Some code here
Else
    ' all your other code here
End If
```

What code you write depends on how you want to handle the error. The above gives you some flexibility, but a "soft fail" where you quietly correct the user's error is also possible

```
If EndDate < StartDate Then
    ' Swap the dates
    TempDate = EndDate
    EndDate = StartDate
    StartDate = TempDate
End If
' all your other code here
```

Always a good idea to work out what potential errors can happen and handle them in the code; leave the `On Error` bits for the unexpected. Even better if you can write the code so that you avoid all the potential errors (including validating the user input like above).